# Apache Oozie throws ClassNotFoundException (org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration) during startup

Tags: jar, classnotfoundexception, oozie

I built the Apache Oozie 5.2.1 from the source code in my MacOS and currently having trouble running it. The ClassNotFoundException indicates a missing class org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration but it is available in both libext/ and the Hadoop file system.

I followed the 1st approach given here to copy Hadoop libraries to Oozie binary distro.
[image]
https://oozie.apache.org/docs/5.2.1/DG_QuickStart.html

I downloaded Hadoop 2.6.0 distro and copied all the jars to libext before running Oozie in addition to other configs, etc as specified in the following blog.

https://www.trytechstuff.com/how-to-setup-apache-hadoop-2-6-0-version-single-node-on-ubuntu-mac/

This is how I installed Hadoop in MacOS. Hadoop 2.6.0 is working fine.
http://zhongyaonan.com/hadoop-tutorial/setting-up-hadoop-2-6-on-mac-osx-yosemite.html

This looks pretty basic issue but could not find why the jar/class in libext is not loaded.

- OS: MacOS 10.14.6 (Mojave)
- JAVA: 1.8.0_191
- Hadoop: 2.6.0 (running in
  the Mac)

```
$ pwd
/Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1
$ ll libext/hadoop-common-2.6.0.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 ckit  1837102431   3.1M 10 May 06:58 libext/hadoop-common-2.6.0.jar
```

```
$ oozie-5.2.1$ bin/oozied.sh run

Setting OOZIE_HOME:          /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1
Setting OOZIE_CONFIG:        /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/conf
Sourcing:                    /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/conf/oozie-env.sh
Setting OOZIE_CONFIG_FILE:   oozie-site.xml
Setting OOZIE_DATA:          /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/data
Setting OOZIE_LOG:           /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/logs
Setting OOZIE_LOG4J_FILE:    oozie-log4j.properties
Setting OOZIE_LOG4J_RELOAD:  10
Setting OOZIE_HTTP_HOSTNAME: C02VR2JSHTDD
Setting OOZIE_INSTANCE_ID:   C02VR2JSHTDD

Setting JETTY_OUT:        /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/logs/jetty.out
Setting JETTY_PID_FILE:        /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/embedded-oozie-server/oozie.pid
Using Java executable from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home/
Using   JETTY_OPTS:
Adding to JETTY_OPTS:     -Doozie.home.dir=/Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1 -Doozie.config.dir=/Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/conf -Doozie.log.dir=/Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/logs -Doozie.data.dir=/Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/data -Doozie.instance.id=C02VR2JSHTDD -Doozie.config.file=oozie-site.xml -Doozie.log4j.file=oozie-log4j.properties -Doozie.log4j.reload=10 -Djava.library.path= -cp /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/embedded-oozie-server/*:/Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/embedded-oozie-server/dependency/*:/Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/lib/*:/Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libtools/*:/Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/embedded-oozie-server

INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/activation-1.1.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/aopalliance-1.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/apacheds-i18n-2.0.0-M15.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/apacheds-kerberos-codec-2.0.0-M15.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/api-asn1-api-1.0.0-M20.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/api-util-1.0.0-M20.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/asm-3.2.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/avro-1.7.4.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/commons-cli-1.2.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/commons-codec-1.4.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/commons-configuration-1.6.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/commons-daemon-1.0.13.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/commons-digester-1.8.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/commons-el-1.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/commons-io-2.4.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/commons-lang-2.6.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/commons-math3-3.1.1.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/commons-net-3.1.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/curator-client-2.6.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/curator-framework-2.6.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/gson-2.2.4.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/guava-11.0.2.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/guice-3.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/guice-servlet-3.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/hadoop-annotations-2.6.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/hadoop-ant-2.6.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/hadoop-archives-2.6.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/hadoop-auth-2.6.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/hadoop-aws-2.6.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/hadoop-common-2.6.0-tests.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/hadoop-common-2.6.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/hadoop-datajoin-2.6.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/hadoop-distcp-2.6.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/hadoop-extras-2.6.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/hadoop-gridmix-2.6.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/hadoop-hdfs-2.6.0-tests.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/hadoop-hdfs-2.6.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/hadoop-hdfs-nfs-2.6.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.6.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.6.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.6.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-2.6.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins-2.6.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.6.0-tests.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.6.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.6.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/hadoop-nfs-2.6.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/hadoop-openstack-2.6.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/hadoop-rumen-2.6.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/hadoop-sls-2.6.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/hadoop-streaming-2.6.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/hadoop-yarn-api-2.6.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell-2.6.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher-2.6.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/hadoop-yarn-client-2.6.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/hadoop-yarn-common-2.6.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/hadoop-yarn-registry-2.6.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/hadoop-yarn-server-applicationhistoryservice-2.6.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.6.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-2.6.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager-2.6.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/hadoop-yarn-server-tests-2.6.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-2.6.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/htrace-core-3.0.4.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/httpclient-4.2.5.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/httpcore-4.2.5.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/jackson-annotations-2.2.3.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/jackson-core-2.2.3.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/jackson-databind-2.2.3.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/java-xmlbuilder-0.4.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/javax.inject-1.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/jersey-client-1.9.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/jersey-core-1.9.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/jersey-guice-1.9.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/jersey-json-1.9.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/jersey-server-1.9.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/jets3t-0.9.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/jettison-1.1.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/jetty-6.1.26.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/jline-0.9.94.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/joda-time-2.5.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/jsch-0.1.42.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/jsr305-1.3.9.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/junit-4.11.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/log4j-1.2.17.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/metrics-core-3.0.1.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/mysql-connector-java-8.0.24.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/paranamer-2.3.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/servlet-api-2.5.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/stax-api-1.0-2.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/xml-apis-1.3.04.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/xmlenc-0.52.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/xz-1.0.jar
INFO: Adding extension: /Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar
/Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/embedded-oozie-server/webapp/ext-2.2 already exists

Setting up oozie DB

Validate DB Connection
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/ckit/platforms/oozie-5.2.1/oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1/libext/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
DONE
DB schema exists

The SQL commands have been written to: /var/folders/hs/7z8yx1n535s5b_rvw3c59kqh34zx3v/T/ooziedb-485151057635515282.sql

Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to sort the above issue and few other ClassNotFoundException by copying the following jar files from extlib to lib. Both folder are in oozie_install/oozie-5.2.1.

- libext/hadoop-common-2.6.0.jar
- libext/commons-configuration-1.6.jar
- libext/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.6.0.jar
- libext/hadoop-hdfs-2.6.0.jar

While I am not sure how many more jars need to be moved from libext to lib while I try to run an example workflow/job in oozie. This fix brought up Oozie web site at http://localhost:11000/oozie/

I am also not sure why Oozie doesn't load the libraries in the libext/ folder.